problem opening Sqlite3 database from JavaScript Web Worker
I'm trying to insert data from an Sqlite3 database into a web page hosted by a Beaglebone black.
Using a JavaScript web worker form an on line example for a number count, the JS worker and HTML page work fine. If I modify the worker code to get the data from a database,and run that in a terminal on the host, that also works fine, the data base is accessed and the data printed out. However, the code will NOT operate as a worker.
HTML code (wkr_tst.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
<p>Count numbers: <output id="result2"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<script>
var w;

function startWorker() {
  if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof(w) == "undefined") {
      w = new Worker("dbase1.js");
    }
    w.onmessage = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
      document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
  }
}

function stopWorker() {
  w.terminate();
  w = undefined;
}
</script>

</body>
</html> 


JavaScript worker:(dbase1.js)
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3")
var i = 0;
const db = new sqlite3.Database("/home/debian/examples/C_BMS/test2.db",sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY );

function timedCount() {
    i=i+1;
   db.all("SELECT * FROM EpiData", [], (err, rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
    })
postMessage(rows);
//postMessage(i);
//postMessage(i+2);
//setTimeout("timedCount()",500);
}
timedCount(); 
db.close();


With 2 different browsers, using the inspect function, both show that the "require(Sqlite3) function is not defined.
I've tried re-installing both Node.js and the squlite3 extension, with the same result.

Web Workers in JS running in the brower don't have access to require("sqlite3") cuz it is a Nodejs module.
I suggest you to separate client side (Web Worker) from server side (Nodejs).
Here is an example of what you can do:
1. Server side code (Nodejs)

Install cors, npm install --save cors or yarn add cors



const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); //this enables cors for everyone, first try this and check if your code works
/*
do this if you only want specific address to have access to the route
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://192.168.0.52',  //replace with the actual frontend URL
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));
*/
const port = 3000; //you can change this port to whatever port you want

const db = new sqlite3.Database('/home/debian/examples/C_BMS/test2.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);

//make an endpoint to fetch data
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    db.all("SELECT * FROM EpiData", [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
            return;
        }
        res.json(rows);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});



2. Web Worker (dbase1.js)


function timedCount() {
    fetch('http://<your-server-ip>:3050/data') // changed this line from `fetch("/data")`
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            postMessage(data);  //send data back to the main thread
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            postMessage('Error fetching data');
        });
}

timedCount();



3. wkr_tst.html


<html>
<body>

<p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
<p>Count numbers: <output id="result2"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<script>
var w;

function startWorker() {
  if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof(w) == "undefined") {
      w = new Worker("dbase1.js");
    }
    w.onmessage = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.data, null, 2);
      document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.data, null, 2);
    };
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
  }
}

function stopWorker() {
  w.terminate();
  w = undefined;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>



Note: Make sure that both your frontend (HTML) and backend (Nodejs) are running on BeagleBone Black and they are served via a web server or nodejs server, and maybe you also have to enable cors (in Nodejs code). Or you can also serve static HTML file with express too.


app.use(express.static('path to your html file'));



Hope this helps you.

Thank you. Without your server side code running, I did at least get the :"Error fetching data" appear on the web page. But: what links the dbse1.js code to the server side code? Sorry if this seems to be a basic question, but I don't see any link..

Thank you. I loaded your versions of dbas1.js and wkr_tst.html. I then put the server side script into a file called dbase_server.js. After loading the "express" module, the latter ran. I changed the port to 3050, due to a conflict with code_server runing on the BBB.  However, I fail to see what links dbase1.js to the now named dbase_server.js. I can see that the latter is listening on 3050, but how is that port called frm dbase1.js?

I went to look in the console inspector of wkr_test.html, and found this error looping: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Digging a little further into the network inspector, the response is "404 not found, Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) Server at 192.168.0.52 Port 80

so it looks like the fetch to "/data" is being made on port 80, while the responder is on port 3050?

changed the fetch command in dbase1.js to: fetch('/data',{url:'192.168.0.52:3050'}), which points at port 3050 on the BBB, also added console.log(".get received"); to server side code after app.get(); in order to detect if this code is being called. So far it is not.

@MikeD I updated the dbase1.js file. Sorry that I forgot to write comment on that line. I updated the timedCount() function.

making your change results in a fetch string of: GET
http://192.168.0.52/templates/http//192.168.0.52:3050/data

I changed the fetch by omitting the http, so "fetch('//192.168.0.52:3050/data')" This actually triggered the dbase_server.js script to read the database!! However, this then resulted in:making fetch dbase1.js:2:13
error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. in the console view of the inspect function in the browser. Network inspector tab gives CORS: missing allow origin,

@MikeD yes, I wrote about cors that you need to enable. I wll again update the code on how to install it.

@MikeD I updated the code. Hope it will help you.

fetch('//192.168.0.52:3050/data',{mode:'no-cors'}) << This worked, but I'm now getting "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" as an error message, but the inspector now shows the correct looking data. So the "fetch" is now working, just need to resolve the data format....

@MikeD remove { mode: 'no-cors' } and install cors as I updated the code. When you do { mode: 'no-cors' } the browser does not allow you to access the response body.

OK, tried that with both app.use statements alternately. failed to run wiht app.use(cors({
^
ReferenceError: cors is not defined

with the mode:n'no-cors' ; the response WAS received ok, but failed to parse due to the square brackets.

@MikeD do you mean like this: [{ "id": 1, "name": "Item 1" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Item 2" }]? This is an array or a list, you can just loop thorugh it. use for loop, .foreach, .map anything you want.

@MikeD can you paste what you got in response here?

{"Dev":0,"Meas":"Volt","C1":3.314,"C2":3.317,"C3":3.317,"C4":3.317,"C5":3.317,"C6":3.315,"C7":3.318,"C8":3.316},{"Dev":0,"Meas":"Temp","C1":26.455,"C2":26.44,"C3":26.443,"C4":26.443,"C5":23.836,"C6":22.872,"C7":null,"C8":null},{"Dev":0,"Meas":"Amps","C1":0,"C2":26.531,"C3":null,"C4":null,"C5":null,"C6":null,"C7":null,"C8":null},{"Dev":0,"Meas":"Ohm","C1":0,"C2":0,"C3":0,"C4":0,"C5":0,"C6":0,"C7":0,"C8":0}]

This is the full response from the database. I changed response.json to response.txt, this got rid of the parsing error, BUT postMessage(data) is returning an empty string.

The response from the database is being seen on Firefox network inspector tab.

Going back to your use cors in dbase_server, I used npm to install coors, this now all works!!
